# Подойдет ли для этого сервлет?

Tags: java, сервер, java-ee, servlet

Здравствуйте.

Мне необходимо написать что-то вроде небольшого форума, где, соответственно, будет регистрация/вход и т.д. Но подключение будет производиться через клиент, написанный на *Java*.

Рационально ли все реализовать на *Java* сервлете/*Servlet*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая тот факт, что в вопросе никакой конкретной информации о приложении (количество одновременных пользователей, количество запросов в секунду, конкретные фичи), то ответ: да, рационально. В той же степени рационально использовать для этого скрипт на Python, Ruby, Perl или PHP, сервис на ASP.NET или самописный сервер на C (ладно, с последним я погорячился). Если нет жёсткого требования реализовывать связь между клиентом и сервером через [RMI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI) (или ещё какой-нибудь специфичной для конкретного языка технологии), то вы вообще не привязаны ни к какому языку или платформе и вольны выбирать любые средства для реализации задачи. Все серверные языки примерно равны в своих возможностях, так что, не имея каких-то конкретных требований, говорить о рациональности выбора той или иной технологии нельзя.